# setState is ignored in handleSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the form submitted value should be 2.

```
this.state = { dog: 1 };
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
handleSubmit(e) {e.preventDefault(); this.setState({dog: 2})}
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}><Button variant="primary" 
type="submit">Submit</Button></Form>
```

Comment: Show the rest of your code - where does the `Form` component come from? Does it pass an event argument to `handleSubmit`?

Comment: Honestly your code logic looks alright? You probably just setting up the class component incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should pass props in `super()`

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { dog: 1 };
}
```

Arrow function would solve the issue of `this`

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({dog: 2})
}

<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <Button variant="primary" type="submit">Submit</Button>
</Form>
```

Comment: that's nice answer but edit Form to be form if he using bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

The setting state is asynchronous hence you might not be able to see the changed state just after setting it.

```
handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  this.setState({dog: 2}, ()=>console.log(this.state.dog))
}
```

It will console `2`.

Answer (score 0):

This will help understanding of how setState occurs:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            dog: 1
        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.setState({ dog: 2 }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.dog)
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { dog } = this.state;
        return (
            <>
                <span>Dog Value : {dog}</span>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <button variant="primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = { dog: 1 };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ dog: 2 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <button> Submit</button>
        <p>{this.state.dog}</p>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

This works just fine. What is Form ? Did you mean form?

Using your code you could try adding handleSubmit to the button's onClick to see if your state updates.